# Configure Azure AD B2C as a AWS API Gateway Authorizer

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, azure, aws-api-gateway, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to configure Azure AD B2C as an Authorizer for AWS API gateways. But it is kept on returning {"message":"Unauthorized"}. I am not able to find the root, I think I have some issue with configuration. Appreciate your prompt help.

- What could be the Issuer URI for B2C that I Can configure in AWS API Gateway. I am trying with https://{tenantID}.b2clogin.com/tfp/{tenantID}/{policy-name}/v2.0/
- Help me understand Token Compatibility Settings Session Behavior. I think there is some issue as well due to that I might be facing the unauthorized issue. A better understanding might help me to resolve the issue. Please go to Azure -> Azure AD B2C -> User Flows -> select any flow - > Under property menu -> Scroll down to Token Compatibility and Session Behavior

[Azure AD B2C ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1dGn.png)

Answer (score 0):

1. try with issuer *https://{tenant name}.b2clogin.com/{tenant
   id}/v2.0/.*
2. Session behavior won't affect authorization.